# How can I get the right column after a join using PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have two MySql tables like the following:

```
Cat
------
id : INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
name : VARCHAR(32)

Cheezburger
-------
id : INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
catId : INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Cat (id)
pattyCount : INT
```

When I perform a `LEFT JOIN` on the two tables using PHP's PDO I'd do the following:

```
$database = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $pasword);
$query = $database->prepare('
    SELECT * FROM Cat
    LEFT JOIN Cheezebuger.id ON Cheezburger.catId = cat.id
    WHERE Cat.id = ?');
$query->bindParam(1, $someId);
$query->execute();
$cat = $query-fetch();
```

My question is, how can I differentiate the `id` field associated with the `Cat` table and the `id` associated with the `Cheezburger` table? `$cat['id']` is giving me the `Cheezburger` `id` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's often inadvisable to `SELECT *`. Instead, be explicit about the columns you want and assign aliases to like-named columns:

```
SELECT
  Cat.id AS catid,
  Cat.name AS name,
  Cheezeburger.id AS chzid,
  ...
FROM 
  Cat LEFT JOIN Cheezebuger.id ON Cheezburger.catId = cat.id
WHERE Cat.id = ?
```

Now, to retrieve `Cat.id`, use `$cat['catid']` and to retrieve `Cheezeburger.id`, use `$cat['chzid']`.

A strong reason against doing `SELECT *` is that if you add more columns later which are not needed in this particular part of your application, you won't be using extra memory on the database server to retrieve unneeded data and fetch it into the web application where it won't be used.  If you happened to add a binary BLOB column later, you could potentially pull over a lot more data unnecessarily.

The other reason is the one you've discovered.  You can invite ambiguity in column names.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was probably something simple like this, just still pretty new to PHP and SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the 'lazy' `*` and specify the fields you want explicitly:

```
SELECT cat.ID AS catID, Cheezeburger.id AS icanhaz ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enumerate the fields, and list them out, so it would be like

```
SELECT cat.id as catId, cat.name, cheezburger.id as cheezId ...
```